# Template Member Specialization of Template Class

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I have a class structure which is

```
template<int T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(){};
    ~MyClass(){};

    template<class K> void foo();
};
```

Now I want to specialize the `foo()` method based upon the value of the integer used in `MyClass<int>`, for instance if int the code we have `MyClass<2>` I want to use a different version of `foo<K>()` to if I had `MyClass<3>`. However I want to still have `foo<K>()` unspecialized on `K`.

So that would mean something like this would be okay

```
MyClass<2> myc2;
MyClass<3> myc3;
myc2.foo<SomeClass>();
myc2.foo<SomeOtherClass>();
myc3.foo<SomeClass>();
myc3.foo<SomeOtherClass>();
```

Is it possible to specialize in this way but not specialize on `K`? I've tried a few combinations with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this is what you want:

```
template<int T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(){};
    ~MyClass(){};

    template<class K> void foo();
};

template<int T>
template<class K>
void MyClass<T>::foo()
{
    std::cout << "general form\n";
}

template<>
template<class K>
void MyClass<2>::foo()
{
    std::cout << "MyClass<2>\n";
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<3> c1;
    c1.foo<int>(); // general form
    MyClass<2> c2;
    c2.foo<int>(); // MyClass<2>
    c2.foo<float>(); // MyClass<2>
}
```

Comment: Hi jrok, you seem to have nailed exactly what I want, unfortunately I tried what you suggested already and it gives error "C2244" - "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration".

Comment: @Dan I use GCC. I'm not an expert in templates, so I'm not sure which compiler is right in this case.

Comment: Did it work on GCC? It seems like it should work for me but I'm using VS2010 which doesn't like it. Unfortunately other bits of the code rely on VS2010 so I might have to work around.

Comment: for MSVC I've had to declare the specializations in the class.  I'vee heard this is a MSVC bug.

Comment: Upon trying this again it seems to actually work. I must have had something else messed up somewhere. I do get confused with templates sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

You might try boost::enable_if, it allows to enable or disable particular specializations of classes and methods. Take a look at examples here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html

Comment: yes it is useful but only on places where SFINAE makes sense, which requires it be in function parameters. not always easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

This works under my Visual C++ 2010:

```
template<int T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(){};
    ~MyClass(){};
    template<class K> void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo() for T" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
template<class K>
void MyClass<2>::foo() {
    std::cout << "foo() for 2" << std::endl;
}

template<>
template<class K>
void MyClass<3>::foo() {
    std::cout << "foo() for 3" << std::endl;
}

void main() {
    MyClass<1>().foo<int>();
    MyClass<2>().foo<float>();
    MyClass<3>().foo<std::string>();
}
```

This prints:

```
foo() for T
foo() for 2
foo() for 3
```

Comment: Yeah I tried it again and it worked, I must have had something else borked somewhere. :)

Answer (score -1):

Don't specialize. Just delegate the call to overloaded function as:

```
template<int T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(){};
    ~MyClass(){};

    template<class K> 
    void foo()
    {
      foo_worker(static_cast<K*>(0)); //delegate to overloaded function
    }
private:
    template<class K>
    void foo_worker(K*)
    {
        //general code goes here
    } 
    void foo_worker(SomeClass*)
    {
        //code when K = SomeClass
    } 
    void foo_worker(SomeOtherClass*)
    {
        //code when K = SomeOtherClass
    } 
};
```

And here is how it would work:

- If `K` is `SomeClass`, then `foo_worker(SomeClass*)` would be called eventually.
- Else if `K` is `SomeOtherClass`, then `foo_worker(SomeOtherClass*)` would be called.
- Else the generic `foo_worker` will be called.

Note the parameter in the `foo_worker` is used to enable the compiler to select the correct  overloaded function.

Comment: Does this help me specialize on `T` only? If so I can't see immediately how.

Comment: @Dan: What does that mean? I didn't get you.

Comment: Well say I have two functions `foo<K>` and `bar<K>` both of which use some generic type `K` but are different functions. Now I would like to give them both the same name and choose which one to call based on the value `T` (while still being able to use any `K`).

Comment: @Dan: Why don't you edit your answer, posting more details, and if possible, output as well for the cases you consider.

Comment: no this is bad. because it gets compiled for both types. then each needs to pass the build according to any K. which is bad, you want the lesser requirement on types, so specialization helps into really NOT building portion of codes for specific types. for example, in your specialization for a class "trait" you could excpect to find ::value to be an accessible type. it is not true in general, you would get build errors in your solution. downvoted.

Comment: @v.oddou: You've no idea what you're talking about. In a class template, IF a member-function is not *used*, then it is NOT compiled at all. And function specialization is a bad thing, is a well-known fact.

Answer (score -1):

Problem usually is specialization of template classes, need to specialize the whole class which is inconvenient if the class has a large interface.  One way is to provide another level of indirection as below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(){};
    ~MyClass(){};

    class fooImpl;

    template<class K> void foo()
    {
       fooImpl::fn<K>();
    }
};

template<>
class MyClass<2>::fooImpl
{
public:
   template <class K> static void fn()
   {
      std::cout << "two : " << typeid(K).name() << "\n";
   }
};

template<>
class MyClass<3>::fooImpl
{
public:
   template <class K> static void fn()
   {
      std::cout << "three : " << typeid(K).name() << "\n";
   }
};

class SomeClass {};
class SomeOtherClass {};

int main()
{
   MyClass<2> myc2;
   MyClass<3> myc3;
   myc2.foo<SomeClass>();
   myc2.foo<SomeOtherClass>();
   myc3.foo<SomeClass>();
   myc3.foo<SomeOtherClass>();

   return 0;
}
```

Then you only have to specialize the implementation classes of foo (fooImpl) and not all the other member functions on MyClass you may want to add.

My Compiler gave the following output:

```
two : class SomeClass
two : class SomeOtherClass
three : class SomeClass
three : class SomeOtherClass
```

Comment: you can specialize the functions, and the normal way to do what you suggest is via inheretance.